# How can I use two Cassandra datasources with Spring Boot and Spring Data?

Tags: java, spring-boot, cassandra, spring-data-cassandra

Is there any way to connect a Spring Boot application to two different Cassandra data sources by using Spring Boot and Spring Data?

I tried to configure 2 different data sources but Spring Boot chooses the first one and ignores the other.

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Spring Boot supports out of the box only singleton data sources and it configures a single `Session` with a single `CassandraTemplate`.

Since Spring Data 2.0, `CassandraTemplate` supports a [`SessionFactory`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/cassandra/docs/current/reference/html/#cassandra.connections) that can route calls to different Cassandra `Session`s. That's something you need to configure yourself:

```
@Configuration
class MyConfig {

  @Bean
  CassandraTemplate cassandraTemplate(CassandraConverter converter) {
    SessionFactory factory = …;
    return new CassandraTemplate(factory, converter);
  }
}
```

You might want to take a look into [`AbstractRoutingSessionFactory`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/cassandra/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/cassandra/core/cql/session/lookup/AbstractRoutingSessionFactory.html) for building your own `Session` router.

Comment: can I get some more tutorial/sample links of the same?

Comment: Hi.. Was a detailed tutorial found for this? I too am trying to do something similar. It will be helpful if some more information on this is shared